# jquery to populate inputs with result of function not working

Tags: jquery

I have the below jquery syntax:

```
 $.post('get_sku_prices', {data:product1.value},function(result) 
 { 
 var counter=1
 $('input[id=price1]').val(result);
 $('input[id=adjustedprice1]').val(result);
 alert(result);
 counter++; 
 });
```

This obviously calls function `get_sku_prices` which returns result(in this case 108). the `alert(result)` does display `108` however the two lines to insert the `108` into the two inputs `price1` and `adjusted1` does not work?

what is wrong with this?

```
 $('input[id=price1]').val(result);
 $('input[id=adjustedprice1]').val(result);
```

Second part of my question is that I want to make the input name dynamic. so I have multiple inputs on my form, price1,price2,price3,price4 etc. as such I want to make the number dynamic.

I have no issues with the loop, this is working correctly however how do I make the input being populated dynamic. so as per my example:

```
$('input[id=price1]').val(result);
$('input[id=price2]').val(result);
$('input[id=price3]').val(result);
$('input[id=price4]').val(result);
```

is it as simple as:

```
$('input[id=price+counter]').val(result);
```

Thanks in advance, appreciate your time and effort.

**UPDATE**

The first part of the question is now working,thanks to the people :-)

I am now trying to get the dynamic section of the syntax working. the commented lines are indeed working. if I want to now change it to be dynamic it does not work. I believe the issue is with the counter.

Looking at the below syntax, the alert repeats and goes 1,2,3,4,etc as you would expect.

```
alert(countertwo);
 $.post('get_sku_prices', {data:product1.value},function(result) 
 { 
 //$('#price1').val(result);
 $('#adjustedprice'+counter).val(result);
 //$('#adjustedprice1').val(result);
 $('#price'+counter).val(result);
 });
```

if I change the syntax to:

```
 $.post('get_sku_prices', {data:product1.value},function(result) 
 { 
    alert(countertwo);
 //$('#price1').val(result);
 $('#adjustedprice'+counter).val(result);
 //$('#adjustedprice1').val(result);
 $('#price'+counter).val(result);
 });
```

The alert now shows '20' on every alert (20 times). 20 being the number of rows. so inside the $.post function the alert is not working?

any ideas on why not and how I can fix this?

Thanks.

Comment: If ID is unique _as it should_ .. `$('#price1').val(result);`

Comment: Thanks Mohammad. appreciated.

Comment: With the update: where is `countertwo` being set and where is it being incremented? Would it be possible for you to post the whole function?

Comment: Hi Joe, the counter is actually being controlled by a php loop: so PHP: `for ($counter=1; $counter<=20; $counter++){...}` Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what about this code (you were missing a semicolon after counter declaration, also):

```
$.post('get_sku_prices', {data:product1.value},function(result) 
 { 
 var counter=1;
 $('#price1').val(result);
 $('#adjustedprice1').val(result);
 alert(result);
 counter++; 
 });
```

and regarding your second question, if you want to populate all the inputs with the same value, the easiest would be to give it a class

```
<input type="text" id="price1" class="inputprice" />
<input type="text" id="price2" class="inputprice" />
<input type="text" id="price3" class="inputprice" />
```

and then in your script, you'll target all elements having class inputprice, and change the value:

```
$('.inputprice').val(result);
```

Comment: Thanks Bartdude, first part of the answer is 100% and working. can you give more clarity on the .theclass?

Comment: @Smudger > Answer edited ! Note that this will probably result in the same result in the background, ie looping on the items, but at least it's a 1 line instruction and it's more readable...